# Postgres SQL: Getting one result per date when table has start and end date columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, range

This is a little similar to [Getting date list in a range in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11391085), but not exactly the same (I think).

I have a SQL table where every row contains a start and end date. I would like to form a query so that for each row, for each date inside this range, I get one result.

For example: `id=1, title=MyRange, start=2012-08-05, end=2012-08-08`

Query: `SELECT * FROM myTyble where id=1 AND ...`

Result:

```
 id=1, title=MyRange, date=2012-08-05
 id=1, title=MyRange, date=2012-08-06
 id=1, title=MyRange, date=2012-08-07
 id=1, title=MyRange, date=2012-08-08
```

I realize that unique and primary key rows will be duplicated in this result set, but that does not matter for me. Any ideas would be very welcome!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can join to [`generate_series`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-srf.html#FUNCTIONS-SRF-SERIES) just as easily as you select from it. Something like this should do the trick:

```
select t.*
from generate_series('2010-01-01'::timestamp, '2013-01-01'::timestamp, '1 day') as s(d)
join your_table t on (s.d between t.start and t.end)
```

You'd supply the real dates you want instead of `2010-01-01` and `2013-01-01` of course.

Older versions, such 8.3, don't have a `generate_series` that works with timestamps but you can fake it by using `generate_series` to produce day offsets from an initial date:

```
select t.*
from generate_series(0, 1096) dt(d)
join your_table t on ('2010-01-01'::date + dt.d between t.start and t.end)
```

As before, adjust the `0`, `1096`, and `'2010-01-01'` to match your data.

Comment: This looks neat (I'd have to benchmark it first, of course) but I get an error using `generate_series` for my Postgres 8.3 installation. Do I need any extra options, extensions or libraries? I get "ERROR:  function generate_series(timestamp without time zone, timestamp without time zone, interval) does not exist. HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts."

Comment: @Jens: 8.3's [`generate_series`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/functions-srf.html#FUNCTIONS-SRF-SERIES) doesn't have a timestamp version but you can fake it as in my update.