# Retrieving row count and returning 0 when no rows

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, date-range, generate-series

I've written a query to retrieve how many website signups I've had every day:

```
SELECT created, COUNT(id)
FROM signups
GROUP BY created
ORDER BY created desc
```

However, this only retrieves rows for days where people have actually signed up. If nobody has signed up in a day, I would like to return 0 for that day. Is there a way to do this using SQL or will I have to parse through the results using PHP?

Comment: if no one signs up there is no created record for that day so it will not display a count for that day.

Comment: What DevZero said, it is not possible for MySQL to infer information it doesn't have. You will have to parse through it using PHP to insert missing days with a count of 0.

Comment: @DevZer0, yes, that's the problem. I was wondering if there was a way to "loop" and insert missing dates with the value of 0. Looks like there isn't.

Comment: You forgot to provide the table definition with the data types of your columns and your version of Postgres.

Comment: @AgmLauncher While it may be not possible in MySQL it is possible in Postgres.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `created` to be of type `date` for lack of information.

Postgres provides the wonderful [**`generate_series()`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-srf.html) to make this easy:

```
SELECT d.created, COUNT(s.id) AS ct
FROM  (
   SELECT generate_series(min(created)
                        , max(created), interval '1 day')::date AS created
   FROM   signups
   ) d
LEFT   JOIN signups s USING (created)
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY 1 DESC;
```

This retrieves minimum and maximum day from your table automatically and provides one row per day in between.

Answer (score 1):

You can use NULLIF function:

```
   SELECT created, NULLIF(COUNT(id), 0)
     FROM signups
 GROUP BY created
 ORDER BY created desc
```

Documentation: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-conditional.html

Comment: That doesn't work because if there are no records in `signups` for that day there's nothing being returned.

Comment: Did you try num rows function after query result? $result = pg_query("QUERY"); pg_num_rows($result); [Doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-num-rows.php)

Answer (score 0):

You should create a calendar table in your database (or generate it in a query) and join it with yours then you will get `0` for empty days

```
SELECT calendar.c_date, COUNT(signups.id)
FROM calendar
left join signups on calendar.c_date=signups.created

GROUP BY c_date
ORDER BY c_date desc
```

[Here is a way to make a calendar date in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11391085/getting-date-list-in-a-range-in-postgresql)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make use of a calendar table that has a series of dates and join with it

```
select cal.created,coalesce(total) as total from calender_table as cal left join
(
SELECT created, COUNT(id) as total
FROM signups
GROUP BY created
) as source on cal.created=source.created
ORDER BY cal.created desc
```