# How to aggregate specific rows in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I am new in PostgreSQL and I wanted to know how we can aggregate 15 min intervals in a table.

for example:

```
Table:
time: count
9:01    1
9:05    2
9:13    3 
9:20    4
9:21    3
9:35    3

Output:
time          count
9:00 - 9:15    6
9:15 - 9:30    7
9:30 - 9:45    3
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11391085/getting-date-list-in-a-range-in-postgresql.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that your time column is an actual date-time field, not just a text field.

To calculate which quarter an event occurred in,  simply truncate the time field to the nearest hour using date_trunc.  Then,  calculate which quarter it fell into by dividing the minute portion by 15 and flooring it.    After that, you can calculate the start/end times by using an interval.

EX:  May, 12 2015 19:46:41.
Truncating this to the hour, you get May, 12 2015 19:00:00.
Calculating the quarter is floor(46/15) = 3
Start time= May, 12 2015 19:00:00 + interval '15 minutes' * 3  (which is 19:45)
End time= May, 12 2015 19:00:00 + interval '15 minutes -1 second' * 4    (which is 19:59)

Now, you have start times and end times and action counts.  All you have to do is group them and sum it all together.

Using the following table structure,

```
create table events (
    time timestamp,
    actions integer
);
```

Running the following query will get you the data you're looking for.

```
SELECT start_time, end_time, sum(actions), count(*)
FROM (
  SELECT 
    date_trunc('hour',time) + (interval '15 minutes'*floor(date_part('minute',time)/15)) as start_time, 
    date_trunc('hour',time) + (interval '15 minutes -1 second'*(floor(date_part('minute',time)/15)+1)) as end_time,
    actions
   from events
) as interval_actions
group by start_time, end_time;
```

I mocked this up in [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ebdd1/3) for you.
Datetime functions for postgres are listed in the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.htm).