# SQL Server: whole weeks total in a calendar month

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want weekly totals in a month. It will not include any  partial week or future weeks. Week starts from Monday  to Sunday.

I have a table structure like

```
Date          Value      -- Comments
----------------------------------------------------------------------   
2016-10-01      7        Ignore this because its not a whole  week in a month
2016-10-05      8        Week 1  
2016-10-07      5        Week 1  
2016-10-11      2        Week 2  
2016-10-15      1        Week 2    
2016-10-17      9        Ignore this because the week is not finished yet
```

OUTPUT

```
 WeekNo         Total
    41             13
    42              3
```

Comment: And what is your expected output? Just add that

Comment: what is that whole week mean?

Comment: For example: In the  current calendar month. we will  ignore the 26Sep-2Oct week and 31Oct-6Nov week because these are not the whole weeks within current month.

Comment: it would mean that values from arbitrary date ranges are omitted, even when you query data of consecutive months... an interesting puzzle, but before investing time, I'd like to question the underlying specification. is this really a valid requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @StartDate datetime = '2011-10-01';
DECLARE @EndDate datetime = '2016-10-31';
SELECT
  CAST(DATEADD(dd, -DATEPART(dw, tblData.RecordDate) + 2, tblData.RecordDate) AS date) AS WeekStart,
  CAST(DATEADD(dd, -DATEPART(dw, tblData.RecordDate) + 8, tblData.RecordDate) AS date) AS WeekEnd,
  SUM(Value) AS Total
FROM tblData

WHERE (@StartDate IS NULL
OR CAST(DATEADD(dd, -DATEPART(dw, tblData.RecordDate) + 2, tblData.RecordDate) AS date) >= CAST(@StartDate AS date))
AND (@EndDate IS NULL
OR CAST(DATEADD(dd, -DATEPART(dw, tblData.RecordDate) + 8, tblData.RecordDate) AS date) <= CAST(@EndDate AS date))
AND CAST(DATEADD(dd, -DATEPART(dw, tblData.RecordDate) + 8, tblData.RecordDate) AS date) < CAST(GETDATE() AS date)
GROUP BY CAST(DATEADD(dd, -DATEPART(dw, tblData.RecordDate) + 2, tblData.RecordDate) AS date),
         CAST(DATEADD(dd, -DATEPART(dw, tblData.RecordDate) + 8, tblData.RecordDate) AS date)
```

Answer (score 1):

The easier way would be to build a Tally "date" table. 
you can generate it from any Tally Table like:

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATE = '20160101'
  , @EndDate DATE = '20161231';

WITH cte AS (
SELECT  DATEADD(DAY, n - 1, @StartDate) AS date
FROM    tally
WHERE   n - 1 <= DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, @EndDate)
)
SELECT 
    c.date 
    ,YEAR(c.date) AS Year
    ,MONTH(c.date) AS Month
    ,DAY(c.date) AS Month
    ,DATEPART(WEEK,c.date) AS Week
    ,CASE WHEN 7<>COUNT(c.date) OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR(c.date),MONTH(c.date),DATEPART(WEEK,c.date)) THEN  0 ELSE 1 END AS isFullWeek
FROM cte c
```

Then you just need to Join it to what ever query you need.

Answer (score 0):

Create a calendar table that meets your request, like this:

```
    create table calendarTable ([date] date, weekNro int)
        go

    insert into  calendarTable 
    select dateadd(d,n,'20160101'), DATEPART(WK,dateadd(d,n,'20151231')) 
    from  numbers where n<500
```

If you don't have a Numbers Table, you must create it first. like this

```
SET NOCOUNT ON    
CREATE TABLE Numbers (n bigint PRIMARY KEY)    
GO    
DECLARE @numbers table(number int);  
WITH numbers(number) as  (   
SELECT 1 AS number   
UNION all   
SELECT number+1 FROM numbers WHERE number<10000  
)  
INSERT INTO @numbers(number)  
SELECT number FROM numbers OPTION(maxrecursion 10000)
INSERT INTO Numbers(n)  SELECT number FROM @numbers
```

Then query your table joining calendar table having in mind actual date for completed week, like this:

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @Kilren but translated into postgres and using generate series from https://stackoverflow.com/a/11391987/10087503 to generate the dates

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATE = '20160101'
  , @EndDate DATE = '20161231';

WITH cte AS (
SELECT i::date AS date FROM generate_series(@StartDate, 
  @EndDate, '1 day'::interval) i
)
SELECT 
    c.date 
    ,DATE_TRUNC('month' ,c.date) AS month_trunc
    ,DATE_PART('week',c.date) AS week
    ,CASE WHEN 7<>COUNT(c.date) 
    OVER (PARTITION BY DATE_TRUNC('month' ,c.date),DATE_PART('week',c.date)) 
    THEN  0 ELSE 1 END AS is_full_week
FROM cte c
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    Select DATEPART(ww, date) , SUM(Case When Comments Like '%1' then Value when Comments Like '%2' then Value else Value end)

from schema.tablename

group by DATEPART(ww,date)
```

I'm sorry if this doesn't work, it's the only way I thought to structure it.

Comment: not clear how this would address the problem described in the question