# PostgreSQL: How to join two tables using between date?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I really don't know how to ask this question of mine.

I'll illustrate it using two tables I needed to join.

## TABLE_1

```
Name    Date
John    01-01-2016
May     04-08-2015
Rose    10-25-2016
Mary    12-15-2015
Ruby    07-07-2017
```

## TABLE_2

```
Signatory       DateFrom    DateTo
President 1     01-01-2015  12-31-2015
President 2     01-01-2016  12-31-2016
```

## RESULT:

```
Name    Date        Signatory
John    01-01-2016  President 2
May     04-08-2015  President 1
Rose    10-25-2016  President 2
Mary    12-15-2015  President 1
Ruby    07-07-2017  NULL
```

All I need to check if the *Date* of **Table_1** is within the *DateFrom* and *DateTo* of Table_2 to get the Signatory field.

How I can do that?

Thanks a lot! ^_^

Comment: Essentially you need a table of every date. Checkout the answers here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11391085/getting-date-list-in-a-range-in-postgresql

Comment: From google search every date from start to finish postgresql https://www.google.com.au/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=every+date+from+start+to+finish+postgresql

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.Signatory
FROM Table_1 AS t1
LEFT JOIN Table_2 AS t2 
   ON t1."Date" BETWEEN t2.DateFrom AND t2.DateTo
```

What you need is just a `LEFT JOIN` with `BETWEEN` in the `ON` clause in order to determine whether `Date` field of `Table_1` falls within any `[DateFrom, DateTo]` interval of `Table_2`.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/97558/3)