# Update a timestamp column to make a sequence of increasing timestamps along a sorted numeric column

Tags: postgresql, datetime, time-series, integer, sql-update

I have a table with column of monotonically increasing integers (`id`). I need to update column `updated_at` (timestamp) to create an increasing series of timestamps, all in the past. The exact step does not matter, as long as the timestamps monotonically increase.

```
create table temp1 (
        id serial not null,
        bar varchar(35),
        updated_at timestamp
        )
;

insert into temp1
    (bar)
    values
    ('val1'),
    ('val2'),
    ('val3')
    ;

select * from temp1;
```

```
 id | bar  | updated_at 
----+------+------------
  1 | val1 | NULL
  2 | val2 | NULL
  3 | val3 | NULL
(3 rows)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way to accomplish this would be to use the date/time math operators. For example, this generates a sequence of timestamps with a start date = 3 months in the past, and incrementing the timestamp in each row by `id` seconds compared with the start date:

```
update temp1
set updated_at = (now() - interval '3 months' + interval '1 second' * id)
    ;

select * from temp1;
```

```
 id | bar  |         updated_at         
----+------+----------------------------
  1 | val1 | 2023-01-06 17:49:59.644966
  2 | val2 | 2023-01-06 17:50:00.644966
  3 | val3 | 2023-01-06 17:50:01.644966
(3 rows)
```

**See also:**

- [PostgreSQL: Documentation: 15: 9.9. Date/Time Functions and Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html)
- [Getting date list in a range in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11391085/967621)
- [Generating time series between two dates in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14113469/967621)